# how to query facebook user's email using graph api?

Tags: email, facebook-graph-api, facebook

i need help to get facebook user's email.  here's what I did.

https://graph.facebook.com/me?scope=email&access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

the result I got back has no email in it.

```
            {
               "id": "7027110",
               "name": "John Mike",
               "first_name": "John",
               "last_name": "Mike",
               "link": "http://www.facebook.com/john.mike",
               "username": "john.mike",
               "location": {
                  "id": "11241875545",
                  "name": "Oakland, New Jersey"
               },
               "gender": "male",
               "timezone": -5,
               "locale": "en_US",
               "verified": true,
               "updated_time": "2011-12-07T16:53:47+0000"
            }
```

also tried to change scope=email to fields=email, still does not work.  whats missing, please help me out

Comment: I don't think you're meant to be able to get that information. It's not available to normal users. It'd also lead to severe spam issues.

Comment: It could be that they just don't have a public email :( here try this: 
`https://graph.facebook.com/me/fql?access_token=<your access token>&q=select%20name,email%20from%20user%20where%20uid=me()` 
or 
`https://graph.facebook.com/me/fql?access_token=<your access token>&q=select%20name,email%20from%20user%20where%20uid%20in%20(select%20uid2%20from%20friend%20where%20uid1%20=me())`

Comment: whatever I did is correct. however, I didnt have permission to query user's email. In order to do that.  the first time user login, i need to ask htem to give me permission.

Answer (score 7):

You can get user email like this: 
`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me?fields=id,name,email`
more detail go [here](https://www.sammyk.me/optimizing-request-queries-to-the-facebook-graph-api)

Answer (score 1):

Did you obtain the `email` extended permission from the user? You can check which permissions your access token has been granted with a call to `/me/permissions`

Answer (score 1):

The user has to authorize you to get this information first.  If it were possible, we would be receiving 100 times more spam than we already receive.

**This [Facebook tool](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/) can help you.**